Escaping quotes inside nested powershell calls
Goal: run a single command from cmd to create a ramdisk using imdisk
Details: I have found that creating a ramdisk with imdisk requires admin privileges and the best way that I have found to open an elevated privilege window from inside cmd and then execute an imdisk command is to use powershell. I'm a powershell and python novice and am having a lot of trouble with the syntax for a command that uses nested python and powershell and has several spaces and double quotes and forward- and back-slashes. The command I want to execute is imdisk -a -s 16G -m X:\ -p "/fs:ntfs /q /y" and so far what I have come up with based on other answers (How do I run a PowerShell script as administrator using a shortcut? and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-7.4) is this
powershell -Command "& {Start-Process powershell -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList \"-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoExit -Command imdisk -a -s 16G -m X:\ -p "/fs:ntfs /q /y"\"}"
I know there needs to be some kind of quote around the imdisk command to keep it all together, but every time I try some amount of `" or \" or \`" around it I get an error that I'm missing a terminator " somewhere. I think maybe wrapping the imdisk command in another "& {}" after the second -Command? Again, I struggle with all the quotes and escaping marks.
Can someone help me get this syntax right?

Remove the two outside double quotes.  The curly brackets will accomplish the same.

Why not using Runas.exe instead of embedding two PowerShell shells for an external command? Anyways, you migth check some similar questions as: How can I start a powershell script with parameters from a batch file, if you really want to go down this rabbit hole.

@iRon I tried using Runas but was having a lot of trouble getting it to run as administrator

you can also use single quotes on the outside so you dont have to escape the inside double quotes

I suspect there are easier ways to solve this avoiding some indirection.
However, I'm answering the question as stated because I've been in nested escaping hell
a few times before.
dos command:
imdisk -a -s 16G -m X: -p "/fs:ntfs /q /y"

powershell invoking powershell:
Start-Process powershell -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList "-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command imdisk -a -s 16G -m X: -p `"/fs:ntfs /q /y`""

dos command invoking powershell (invoking powershell):
powershell -Command "& {Start-Process powershell -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList \"-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command imdisk -a -s 16G -m X: -p \`\"/fs:ntfs /q /y\`\" \"}"

So when escaping the dos command into powershell, you have to use backtick ` to escape double quotes within the powershell string.
Then, when escaping the whole thing for cmd.exe again, you need to escape the backtick and double quote with \.
In a humourous meta twist, I had to search how to put a backtick in a code block while writing this.

Thank you! Executing the "powershell invoking powershell" version in powershell just seems to execute imdisk without the arguments, but once it's all wrapped up and put in dos it works.

Whoops - well spotted. That line works with the spaces removed from  /q /y but not sure why.
